# How do I get the total amount on all items on a for loop?

Tags: java, android, loops, data-structures

I have 6 orders. I looped the 6 orders in order to get each order's total price.

> What I want to do is to add every order's total price on the loop, and
>   then compare it to the `authorized amount`.

Let us say, **authorized amount is 2000**.

> What happens is it compares the authorized amount to the PER ORDER
>   TOTAL PRICE, instead of the **ALL ORDERS TOTAL PRICE**.

Here is a sample code:

```
for (Entity checkout : checkouts) {
                List<Entity> selectedJOs = AppUtil.getEntities(AppUtil.getListIds(checkout, "job-orders"), jobOrders);
                long finalGrandTotalAmount = 0;

                for (Entity job_order : selectedJOs) {

                    grandTotalAmount = 0;
                    long totalJobOrderPurchasedAmount = 0;
                    long totalJobOrderDeliveryFee = 0;
                    long totalJobOrderShoppingFee = 0;
                    long totalJobOrderDiscount = 0;
                    totalJobOrderRecalled = 0;
                    long totalCampaignDiscount = 0;

                    if (!job_order.attributes.status.equals("cancelled")) {
                        totalJobOrderPurchasedAmount += (job_order.attributes.purchased_deliverables_amount_in_cents + job_order.attributes.non_membership_fee_in_cents);
                        totalJobOrderDeliveryFee += job_order.attributes.delivery_fee_in_cents;
                        totalJobOrderShoppingFee += job_order.attributes.shopping_fee_in_cents;
                        totalJobOrderRecalled += job_order.attributes.recalled_deliverables_amount_in_cents;

                        List<Entity> selectedCampaigns = AppUtil.getEntities(AppUtil.getListIds(job_order, "job-order-fmcg-campaign-vouchers"), campaignDiscounts);


                        for (Entity campaignDiscount : selectedCampaigns) {
                            totalCampaignDiscount += campaignDiscount.attributes.discount_in_cents;

                        }
                        for (Entity discount : discounts) {
                            long job_order_discount;

                            if (discount.relationships.job_order.data.id.equals(job_order.id)) {
                                long purchase_amount = job_order.attributes.purchased_deliverables_amount_in_cents;
                                if (discount.attributes.sum_in_cents_off <= 0) {
                                    job_order_discount = Math.round(purchase_amount * discount.attributes.percent_off);
                                } else {
                                    job_order_discount = discount.attributes.sum_in_cents_off;
                                }

                                totalJobOrderDiscount += job_order_discount;
                            }
                        }


                        long discounts_total = totalJobOrderDiscount > 0 ? totalJobOrderDiscount + totalCampaignDiscount : totalCampaignDiscount;
                        grandTotalAmount = (totalJobOrderPurchasedAmount - discounts_total) + (totalJobOrderShoppingFee + totalJobOrderDeliveryFee) - job_order.attributes.credit_amount_of_cents;

                        boolean isLoginPrimary = true;

                        List<Entity> selected_consignments = AppUtil.getEntities(AppUtil.getListIds(job_order, "consignments"), consignments);

                        for (Entity consignment : selected_consignments) {
                            if (consignment.attributes.primary) {
                                Entity user = AppUtil.getEntity(consignment.relationships.user.data.id, users);
                                isLoginPrimary = user.relationships.profile.data.type.equals("runner-profiles") && user.id.equals(Preferences.getString(Prefkey.session_user_id)) && isLoginPrimary;
                            }
                        }

                        if (job_order.relationships.completed_by_user.data != null) {
                            if (job_order.relationships.completed_by_user.data.id.equals(Preferences.getString(Prefkey.session_user_id))) {
                                if (checkout.attributes.payment_mode.equals("credit-card")) {
                                    if (checkout.attributes.authorized_amount_in_cents < grandTotalAmount) {
                                        grandTotalAmountCc += checkout.attributes.authorized_amount_in_cents - totalJobOrderRecalled;
                                        grandTotalAmountCash += checkout.attributes.paid_cash_difference_in_cents;
                                    } else {
                                        grandTotalAmountCc += grandTotalAmount - totalJobOrderRecalled;
                                        grandTotalAmountCash += 0;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    grandTotalAmountCash += grandTotalAmount - totalJobOrderRecalled;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: The section where you check for "all" orders, should be outside of the loop, you are checking the "each" order's total price.

Comment: @DylanAng Yes. Tried that and it works but I will also be getting miscomputations for `grandTotalAmountCash` since I also need to check the per JO's total amount.

Comment: You will just have to add another method for checking that. Your code is a bit hard to understand and has a few redundant brackets/calculations. 
Might want to tidy it up and double-check your own calculations :)

Comment: Now works. I just placed the `grandTotalAmount` under the checkouts loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for every loop, you are resetting grandTotalAmount. By making it global, will fix your problem.